# Get value from Pages data type in page types in Kentico

Tags: macros, kentico

I have a *Pages* data type as one of the page type fields.

[image: Image Text]

But when I try to access it's value using the Macro like `{% JoinPageLink %}`, I don't get any values (empty).

I can access rest of the fields in that page type.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pages type creates an *ad-hoc relationship name* for the page type.  Its value in the page type table in the database is always `NULL`, so when you try to access it using `{%JoinPageLink%}`, you won't get a value.  Kentico describes this as [Advanced Content Modeling](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/working-with-pages/modeling-content-by-reusing-pages).

To make use of the Pages type, you will need to use something like a transformation to retrieve your data.  There is a page on DevNet that gives detail on using a listing control to display the relationship information: [Displaying related pages using web parts](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/displaying-data-advanced-scenarios/displaying-related-pages-using-named-relationships#Displayingrelatedpagesusingnamedrelationships-Displayingrelatedpagesusingwebparts)

Comment: I ended up using a URL selector instead of Pages data type.